# Upload image without form action using dropzone in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, dropzone.js

Upload image without form action using dropzone in CodeIgniter. I need to upload an image without the form action in dropzone. that means, there are one form, dropzone image and other fields are in the form. First when we selecting an image, automatically upload the image and save in the database. And add other fields then submit the form action.

Answer (score 0):

you can Upload image using AJAX with button but a button must be under the form tag with id

**View**

```
<form action="<?php echo SURL; ?>admin/registered_students/" id="file_completion_form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<td>
                                    <input type="file" data-validation="" style="display: inline" name="undertaking" id="undertaking" value="" placeholder="" multiple="">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="hidden" id="student_id" name="student_id" value="<?=$student_id;?>">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info chk2" id="upload_undertaking">
                                        <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="alert" style="display: none" id="msg">Updated</span>
                                </td>
                                <td id="download_undertaking">
                                    <a href="<?php echo SURL.'file/download/'.$files[0]['undertaking'];?>">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info chk2" id=""><i class="fa fa-download"></i></button>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$('#upload_undertaking').click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = new FormData();
        var form_data = $('#file_completion_form').serializeArray();
        $.each(form_data, function (key, input)
        {
           data.append(input.name, input.value);
        });
        //input quatation
        var quotation_wip = $('input[name="undertaking"]')[0].files;
        if(quotation_wip.length>0)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < quotation_wip.length; i++)
            {
                data.append("undertaking[]", quotation_wip[i]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
            exit;
        }
        data.append('key', 'value');
        var student_id =  $('#student_id').val();
        $.ajax(
        {
            url:URL+'file_completion/'+student_id,
            type:'POST',
            data:data,
            cache:false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success:function(data)
            {
                if(data==2)
                {
                    window.location.href=URL+'index/'+student_id;
                }
                else
                {
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    // alert( obj.undertaking );
                    $("#undertaking span").html(obj.undertaking);
                    $("#download_undertaking").html('<a href="'+URL+'download/'+obj.undertaking+'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info chk2" id=""><i class="fa fa-upload"></i></button></a>');
                    $("#msg").show();
                    setTimeout(function()
                    {
                        $("#msg").hide(); 
                    }, 
                    10000);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

**Controller**

```
    public function file_completion1($student_id='',$document_name='')
{
    // if($this->input->post('student_id'))
    // {
    // echo $this->input->post($student_id);
    // echo($student_id).'-';
    // echo($document_name);
    // exit();
        $filename=array();
        if(count($_FILES['copy_of_paid_fee_challan']['name']) > 0 && $_FILES['copy_of_paid_fee_challan']['name'] !='')
        {
            $files = $_FILES['copy_of_paid_fee_challan'];
            $count = count($_FILES['copy_of_paid_fee_challan']['name']);
            //echo $_FILES['file']['name'];exit();
            for($i=0; $i<$count;$i++)
            {
                $config = array();
                $projects_folder_path = './assets/uploads/';
                $thumb = $projects_folder_path . 'thumb';
                $_FILES['copy_of_paid_fee_challan']['name']     = $files['name'][$i];
                $_FILES['copy_of_paid_fee_challan']['type']     = $files['type'][$i];
                $_FILES['copy_of_paid_fee_challan']['tmp_name'] = $files['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES['copy_of_paid_fee_challan']['error']    = $files['error'][$i];
                $_FILES['copy_of_paid_fee_challan']['size']     = $files['size'][$i];   
                // $file_ext  = ltrim(strtolower(strrchr($_FILES['copy_of_paid_fee_challan']['name'],'.')),'.');  
                // $file_name =    'oppein-'.date('YmdGis').'.'.$file_ext;        
                $config['upload_path']      = $projects_folder_path;
                $config['allowed_types']    = '*';
                $config['encrypt_name']     = TRUE;
                $config['overwrite']        = TRUE;
                $config['file_name']        = $_FILES['copy_of_paid_fee_challan']['name'];
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                if(!$this->upload->do_upload('copy_of_paid_fee_challan'))
                {
                    $error_file_arr = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());                
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('err_message', $error_file_arr['error']);
                    $r=2;
                    echo json_encode($r);
                    exit();
                }
                else
                {
                    $data['delete_record'] = $this->Common_model->select_single_records('uploads',$where=array('student_id'=>$student_id));
                    if(file_exists($projects_folder_path.$data['delete_record']['undertaking']))
                    {
                        unlink($projects_folder_path.$data['delete_record']['undertaking']);
                    }
                    $data_image_upload = array('upload_image_data' => $this->upload->data());
                    $image_name =$data_image_upload['upload_image_data']['file_name']; 
                    $full_path = $data_image_upload['upload_image_data']['full_path'];
                    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
                    $this->load->library('image_lib');
                    $config['image_library']    = 'GD2';
                    $config['source_image']     = './assets/uploads/' . $image_name;
                    $config['maintain_ratio']   = TRUE;
                    $config['master_dim']   = 'auto';
                    $config['quality']  = 70;
                    $config['width'] = 1024;
                    $config['height'] = 768;
                    $config['new_image'] = './assets/uploads/' . $image_name;
                    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
                    $this->image_lib->resize();
                    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------            
                }
                $filename[] = $image_name;
            } // end for loop                      
        }
        foreach ($filename as $key => $value)
        {
            $insert_image=array(
                'copy_of_paid_fee_challan'=> $value,
                // 'student_id' => $student_id,
                // 'stage_id' => $stage_id,
                'update_date' => date("Y-m-d g:i:s"),
                // 'category_status' => 1,
                // 'user_id' =>$this->session->userdata('user_id'),
            );
            // echo "<pre>";
            // print_r ($insert_image);
            // echo "</pre>";
            // exit();
            $add_image = $this->Common_model->update_table('uploads',$where=array('student_id'=>$student_id),$insert_image);                           
        }
        if ($add_image)
        {
            $record = $this->Common_model->select_single_records('uploads',$where=array('student_id'=>$student_id));
            echo json_encode($record);
        }
    // }
    // else
    // {
    //  $data['active']='registered_students';
    //  $this->load->view('admin/header',$data);
    //  $data['student_id']=$student_id;
    //  $data['error']='';
    //  $this->load->view('registration/file_completion',$data);
    //  $this->load->view('admin/footer',$data);
    // }
}
```